# Fog deprecation warnings when starting Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fog

I migrated my Rails app to Rails 6.0.1 and every time I startup the server I get these Fog deprecation warnings. How can I get rid of them?
Funny enough I have a cloned version of this app, which doesn't give these warnings...

```
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Atmos::Storage
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Storage::Atmos is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Clodo::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::Clodo is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::DigitalOcean::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::DigitalOcean is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Dnsimple::DNS
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::DNS::Dnsimple is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::DNSMadeEasy::DNS
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::DNS::DNSMadeEasy is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Fogdocker::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::Fogdocker is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Dreamhost::DNS
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::DNS::Dreamhost is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Dynect::DNS
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::DNS::Dynect is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Ecloud::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::Ecloud is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Glesys::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::Glesys is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::GoGrid::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::GoGrid is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Google::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::Google is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Google::DNS
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::DNS::Google is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Google::Storage
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Storage::Google is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::IBM::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::IBM is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::IBM::Storage
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Storage::IBM is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::InternetArchive::Storage
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Storage::InternetArchive is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Linode::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::Linode is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Linode::DNS
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::DNS::Linode is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::BareMetalCloud::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::BareMetalCloud is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Rackspace::CDN
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::CDN::Rackspace is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Rackspace::CDN v2
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::CDN v2::Rackspace is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Rackspace::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::Rackspace is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Rackspace::Compute v2
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute v2::Rackspace is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Rackspace::DNS
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::DNS::Rackspace is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Rackspace::Storage
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Storage::Rackspace is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Rackspace::Databases
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Databases::Rackspace is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Rage4::DNS
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::DNS::Rage4 is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::PowerDNS::DNS
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::DNS::PowerDNS is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::ProfitBricks::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::ProfitBricks is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::SakuraCloud::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::SakuraCloud is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::SakuraCloud::Volume
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Volume::SakuraCloud is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::SakuraCloud::Network
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Network::SakuraCloud is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::SakuraCloud::DNS
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::DNS::SakuraCloud is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Serverlove::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::Serverlove is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Softlayer::Account
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Account::Softlayer is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Softlayer::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::Softlayer is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Softlayer::DNS
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::DNS::Softlayer is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Softlayer::Network
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Network::Softlayer is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Softlayer::Storage
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Storage::Softlayer is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::StormOnDemand::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::StormOnDemand is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::StormOnDemand::Network
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Network::StormOnDemand is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::StormOnDemand::Storage
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Storage::StormOnDemand is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::StormOnDemand::DNS
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::DNS::StormOnDemand is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::StormOnDemand::Billing
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Billing::StormOnDemand is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::StormOnDemand::Monitoring
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Monitoring::StormOnDemand is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::StormOnDemand::Support
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Support::StormOnDemand is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::StormOnDemand::Account
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Account::StormOnDemand is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::StormOnDemand::VPN
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::VPN::StormOnDemand is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Vcloud::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::Vcloud is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::VcloudDirector::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::VcloudDirector is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Vmfusion::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::Vmfusion is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Voxel::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::Voxel is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::CloudSigma::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::CloudSigma is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Openvz::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::Openvz is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::OpenNebula::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::OpenNebula is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Aliyun::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::Aliyun is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::Aliyun::Storage
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Storage::Aliyun is deprecated
```

Comment: Did you update the gem 'fog-core'??

Comment: No, the fog gem is fixed at a certain version

Comment: What fog and/or fog-core versions are you on?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm seeing the same warning and is quite annoying every time I invoke "rails" commands.

Comment: My versions are fog (2.2.0) and fog-core (~> 2.1)

Comment: Nope, no solution yet, but very annoying.

Comment: Which version of fog have you fixed it to?

Comment: @ClemensKofler latest release  fog 2.2.0 https://github.com/fog/fog/releases/tag/v2.2.0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Workaround solution: Stick these 2 lines above Bundler.require in your `config/application.rb`

```
...

require 'fog/core'
Fog::Logger[:deprecation] = nil

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

...
```

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, you're using the whole `fog` library. Is there a specific reason why you're the full library, say, `fog-aws`? IMO there's very little benefit to using the full `fog` library unless you have some kind of higher level app/library that interacts with all the providers that `fog` offers. So I'd suggest to just require the library/libraries you need and leave the rest. This could potentially get rid of the deprecation warnings.

Comment: No specific reason, that's the way it has been setup many years ago in the application. Until Rails 6 this was no problem and didn't give these warnings.